# Не могу десериализовать обьект в список

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация, десериализация

Прошу помощи, имеется следующая проблема с десериализацией. Есть список машин, при добавление в который, список сериализуется в файл. Сериализация проходит без проблем, но вот обратно достать список из файла не получается, выдает следующую ошибку :

> Исключение типа "System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException" возникло в System.Runtime.Serialization.dll, но не было обработано в коде пользователя
>   Дополнительные сведения: Ошибка в строке 1, позиция 112. Ожидается элемент "Car" из пространства имен "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/b_firstService".. Обнаружен "Element" с именем "ArrayOfCar", пространство имен "".

Подскажите пожалуйста из-за чего может не работать десериализация?

**Сервер**

```
public class WorkCar:IWorkCar
{
    public int global_id = 0;
    public List<Car> Cars = new List<Car>();
    public List<Car> GetCars()
    {
        Cars = ReadCars(fileName: "cars.txt");

        return Cars;
    }

    public void AddCars(Car car)
    {
        global_id++;
        car.id = global_id;
        Car z = new Car { modelName = car.modelName, regnum = car.regnum, mark = car.mark, category = car.category };
        Cars.Add(car); //добавили новый

        //Сохранили всё
        var ds = new DataContractSerializer(Cars.GetType());
        using (Stream s = File.Create("person.xml"))
            ds.WriteObject(s, Cars); // Сериализация
        ;
        SaveChanges("cars.txt");
    }

    public void DelCar(int id)
    {
        Cars.Remove(Cars.Find(e => e.id.Equals(id)));
    }

    public void SaveChanges(string fileName)
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(Cars.GetType());
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
        {
            ser.Serialize(writer, Cars);
        }
    }

    public List<Car>  ReadCars(string fileName)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName,
        FileMode.Open);
        XmlDictionaryReader reader =
            XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(fs, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Car));

        // Deserialize the data and read it from the instance.
        List<Car> cars =
            (List<Car>)ser.ReadObject(reader, true);
       reader.Close();
        fs.Close();
        return cars;
    }
}
```

**Клиент**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WorkCarClient workcar = new WorkCarClient                                                                                         ("BasicHttpBinding_IWorkCar");
        int global_id = 0;
        string action = "0";
        Console.WriteLine("Добрый день");
        while (action != "4")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Что вы хотите сделать:\n" +
                  "1 - Добавить запись об автомобиле\n" +
                    "2 - Просмотреть все записи\n" +
                     "3 - Удалить запись\n" +
                      "4 - Выход\n"
                );
            action = Console.ReadLine();
            if (action == "1")
            {
                Car car = new Car();
                Console.WriteLine("Введите название модели автомобиля");
                car.modelName = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Введите название марки");
                car.mark = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Регистрационный номер");
                car.regnum = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Категория автомобилей");
                car.category = Console.ReadLine();
              //  car.create = DateTime.Now;
                workcar.AddCars(car);


                Console.WriteLine("Машина добавлена");
            }

            else if (action == "2")
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Car[] spisok = workcar.GetCars();

                if (spisok.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Car car in spisok)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("№" + car.id + ":" +car.modelName+" " +car.mark+",Регистрационный номер:"+car.regnum );
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Машин в базе данных нет!\n");
                }
            }
            else if (action == "3")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Машину с каким номером удалить?");
                string id = Console.ReadLine();
                workcar.DelCar(Convert.ToInt32(id));
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("ДО свидания!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Класс, описывающий машины**

```
[DataContract]
public class Car
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string modelName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string mark { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string category { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string regnum { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime create { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется у вас проблема в этих строчках:

```
DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Car));
List<Car> cars = (List<Car>)ser.ReadObject(reader, true);
```

Не знаком сильно с `XML`, но по логике, вы в `ser` указываете данные в единичном экземпляре `Car`, но потом пытаетесь перевести все это дело в `(List<Car>)`. У вас скорей всего должны быть одинаковые типы во всех местах, а именно в `DataContractSerializer(typeof(Car))` тип менять на `List<Car>`.

Но опять же, мои догадки и наблюдения, с `XML` не знаком.

Comment: Cпасибо, добрый человек :) Все заработало:)

Comment: @АлександрЛожковой Да на здоровье. Впредь, будьте повнимательней с типами ;-)